# Installing Ubuntu, stuck on partitioning

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer and I'm stuck on partitioning.

I get the message:

"Some of the partitions you created are to small. Please make the following partitions at least this large: /2.9GB If you do not go back to the partitioner and increase the size of these partitions the installation may fail."

I am a beginner at this. Can somebody show me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough free space.

Try to free some and give "/" more space.

You'll need to resize your "/" partition,

Resizing partition with GParted:

> http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId335513

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The questioner is asking how to create more space.